# Photoshopping text on cable

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, text, 3d

For a mockup, I need to add some text to a photo of a piece of cable. It has to look like the text is printed directly on the cable.

So far I've tried to do it in Photoshop. I drew a path along the cable and placed the text along that, but it doesn't look quite right, because the letters don't curve around the cable vertically. The warp tool is usually effective for correcting something like this, but it didn't give me precise control on the curved long strings of text. Any ideas how to achieve this is very much appreciated.

Here's an example photo:

[image: Example:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this seems like it's going to take a lot of finagling and trial and error. Have you tried using the 'puppet warp tool'? I changed the string of text to a smart object so I could still edit it and made the puppet warp a smart filter. This would allow you to hit every letter to curve it. Alternatively, I think the warp tool should work just fine (and actually maybe even better), it'll just take time. Lastly, is the liquify tool, which should probably make this work pretty straightforward.

**PUPPET TOOL**
[image: Puppet Tool]

**WARP TOOL**
[image: Warp Tool]

**LIQUIFY**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This may be the only way forward, yes. I didn't think about using liquify. It may come in handy, but so far I am getting the best results from the warp tool. It works great for curving the text when it is horizontal or vertical, but is difficult to use when it is diagonal. Is is possible to rotate bounding box and mesh of the warp tool? Or do you know of a workaround?

Comment: You can rotate the bounding box and then apply the warp tool to that rotated box (this will make the mesh also rotated), but as soon as you apply the changes, the bounding box switches back to being straight again. I'm not sure if that's what you're asking or not.

Comment: It's a bit dificult to explain - this image may help: http://imgur.com/qgFLFFB 
I would like to rotate the mesh, when the text is diagonal.

Comment: The only way I know how would be like this: http://imgur.com/iHZLMNG

1. create text  
2. change into smart object  
3. command+T to transform and rotate  
4. right click and select warp after rotated